# how to insert data in my sql using else if in jsp

Tags: java, ajax, jsp

Hi  I'm trying to insert data in `mysql` but my page throw no response!
pease can anyone help me about it?

Code runs but `println()` is not displaying

```
  //<%@page import= "java.sql.*"%>   

   // <%@ page import="java.util.Random"%>    

    <%

        String dt = request.getParameter("dt");      

        String particular = request.getParameter("vas");     

        String emp = request.getParameter("emp");       


        String amt = request.getParameter("amt");     

        int amnt = Integer.parseInt(amt);     


        //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");    

        //Connection con = //DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/furqania", "root", "khan");       

        Statement st = con.createStatement();        

        if (particular == "amanatraseedi")    
     {
            Random rnd = new Random();     

            int rn = rnd.nextInt(9000) + 10000;      

            String sr = "AMT" + rn;      

           // int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into      amanatraseedi='"+particular+"'(transactionid,dt,amount,empid) values('" + sr + "','" + dt + "','" + amnt + "','" + emp + "')");      

            if (i > 0) {
                out.println("Amanat raseedi successful!");     

            } else {

                out.println("something went wrong!");       

            }
        } 
        else if (particular == "amadhisab")    
     {
            Random rnd = new Random();

           int rn = rnd.nextInt(9000) + 10000;
                    String sr = "AMD" + rn;
            int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into amadhisab='"+particular+"' (transactionid,dt,amount,empid) values('" + sr + "','" + dt + "','" + amnt + "','" + emp + "')");        

            if (i > 0) {

               out.println("Amad hisab successful!");

       } 
         else {

               out.println("something went wrong!");
                }
        }
        st.close();
        con.close();  
    %>
```

Comment: 1) Use `.equals` to compare Strings 2) Dont use scriptlets

Comment: 3) Consider formatting your code with proper line spacing and indentation.

Comment: 4) Be clear when asking a question on `SO`

Comment: 5) Protect against [sql injection](http://xkcd.com/327/)..

Comment: Debug the flow using alerts.